# How to mention username in bot message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to have the user tagged instead of the ID mentioned (I've tried ${user.username} ) but it still doesn't actually mention the said user that the command runs on

Currently the command is **$cake** "**User tag**" but the bot won't physically mention them instead just write either their username or include there discriminator at the end.

So the code is

```
      recentUsers.push(message.author.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    recentUsers.splice(recentUsers.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
  }, COOLDOWN * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      color: Cuckbot.colors.GREEN,
      description: ` You have given one cake to ${user.id} `
```

Comment: Is this DiscordJS?

Comment: Yes, this is coded within DiscordJS

Comment: I'm pretty sure that just `\`... cake to ${user}\`` should mention the user

Comment: Omg. The one thing I didn't try. Yup. It worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to send it like this *(instead of `user.id`, just `user`)*:

```
description: ` You have given one cake to ${user} `
```

It will convert the user to a String, and that conversion (with DiscordJS) makes it mentionable.
I'm not sure if it will actually mention the user (with the notification) but it will definitely make it clickable.